# How to redirect MacBook Pro audio to my TV?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, hdmi, television

I just connected my MacBook Pro 2013 to my TV using HDMI. The visuals are working, but the TV does not get the audio from my MacBook. How can I redirect the audio from my MacBook to my TV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold the **Option** key and click on the **Volume/Sound** icon on your **Menu Bar**.  When you're connected via HDMI, you should have an option show in the local menu to select that connection to feed the audio through rather than the standard audio output.

Answer (score 1):

If you've removed the Sound menu bar item, you can also change the output device through **System Preferences** → **Sound** → **Output**. There, you can change it by selecting it from the list.